# Django controller method to list the top characters, guilds, and killers

Tags: python, generics, url, django

I've been reading the Chapter 8 of [this book](http://www.djangobook.com/en/2.0/chapter08.html).

Here's the view I'm currently coding. It list all characters/guilds according to the type of URL.

> ```
> /ranking -> List Top 50 Characters
>
> /ranking/guild -> List top guilds
>
> /ranking/pvp -> list top killers
> ```

```
def ranking(request, type):
    if type=='':
        queryset_list = Character.objects.annotate(num_resets=Count('resets')).order_by('-resets').select_related('account')[:50]
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'states':STATES, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}
        template = 'ranking_character.html'
    elif type=='guild':
        queryset_list = Guild.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {'object_list' : queryset}
        template = 'ranking_guild.html'

    elif type=='pvp':
        queryset_list = Character.objects.filter(pk_count__gt=0).annotate(total=Count('pk_count')).order_by('-pk_count')[:50]
        paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)

        page = request.GET.get('page')
        try:
            queryset = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            queryset = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
            context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}
        template = 'ranking_pvp.html'

    return render(request,template,context)
```

It's possible to make it more "generic"? How can I abstract this different `queryset`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally the way to refactor is to proceed step by step. For example, you might start with the [extract method](http://refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html) combined with the [decomposition of conditionals](http://refactoring.com/catalog/decomposeConditional.html).

This would result in:

```
def _ranking_without_type(request):
    queryset_list = Character.objects.annotate(num_resets=Count('resets')).order_by('-resets').select_related('account')[:50]
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'states':STATES, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}

    template = 'ranking_character.html'
    return context, template

def _ranking_by_guild(request):
    queryset_list = Guild.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'object_list' : queryset}
    template = 'ranking_guild.html'
    return context, template


def _ranking_by_pvp(request):
    queryset_list = Character.objects.filter(pk_count__gt=0).annotate(total=Count('pk_count')).order_by('-pk_count')[:50]
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)

    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}
    template = 'ranking_pvp.html'
    return context, template


def ranking(request, type):
    if type=='':
        context, template = _ranking_without_type(request)
    elif type=='guild':
        context, template = _ranking_by_guild(request)

    elif type=='pvp':
        context, template = _ranking_by_pvp(request)

    return render(request,template,context)
```

Run the tests, and check that they still pass. (you have tests, don't you?)

In the next step I would do what Caridorc proposed.

You would have the following code:

```
def _queryset(request, paginator):
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        queryset = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        queryset = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return queryset


def _ranking_without_type(request):
    queryset_list = Character.objects.annotate(num_resets=Count('resets')).order_by('-resets').select_related('account')[:50]
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    queryset = _queryset(request, paginator) 
    context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'states':STATES, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}
    template = 'ranking_character.html'
    return context, template

def _ranking_by_guild(request):
    queryset_list = Guild.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    queryset = _queryset(request, paginator) 
    context = {'object_list' : queryset}
    template = 'ranking_guild.html'
    return context, template

def _ranking_by_pvp(request):
    queryset_list = Character.objects.filter(pk_count__gt=0).annotate(total=Count('pk_count')).order_by('-pk_count')[:50]
    paginator = Paginator(queryset_list, 10)
    queryset = _queryset(request, paginator) 
    context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}
    template = 'ranking_pvp.html'
    return context, template

def ranking(request, type):
    if type=='':
        context, template = _ranking_without_type(request)
    elif type=='guild':
        context, template = _ranking_by_guild(request)

    elif type=='pvp':
        context, template = _ranking_by_pvp(request)

    return render(request,template,context)
```

How about refactoring that "template"?

```
def ranking(request, type):
    template = 'ranking_{0}.html'.format(type if type != '' else 'character')
    if type=='':
        context = _ranking_without_type(request)
    elif type=='guild':
        context = _ranking_by_guild(request)

    elif type=='pvp':
        context = _ranking_by_pvp(request)

    return render(request,template,context)
```

now the *ranking** functions don't return the template anymore, you can remove the second return type from the ranking_* functions.

Finally, you could use a dispatch mapping, e.g., :

```
ranking_by_types = {
   '': _ranking_without_type,
   'guild': _ranking_by_guild,
   'pvp', _ranking_by_pvp,
} 

def ranking(request, type):
    template = 'ranking_{0}.html'.format(type if type != '' else 'character')
    context = ranking_by_types[type](request)
    return render(request,template,context)
```

As you can see, functions will be pretty short. IMHO, they should in general not be longer than 10 lines, although some authors claim they should be at most 3 lines long (others up to 20).

Comment: Thank you ! Just one more thing. Should I study CBV(Class-Based View) and maybe refactor to it?

Comment: You can't use `Paginator(queryset_list, 10)` in `ranking` because you need the `queryset_list` created in each `_ranking*` helper functions.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger thanks, I missed that. Refactoring without testing/running the program is hard :D

Comment: @Bruno: I think you have multiple ways to refactor that code. However, how many functions _ranking_* do you have? If they are only 3, well, there is no point in refactoring - I would stop here. However, if they are let's say > 10-15(*many*!), then I would start thinking how to generalize. As you can see, the central point of the functions is the queryset list. So, you could even further refactor all those queries in a map (they are lazily evaluated, so it's okay). Then, the only changing bit would be the "context". You would have to think about it :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you can just make a function to get the queryset and re-use it:

```
def queryset_from_page():
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        return paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        return paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        return paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

Also why is `context` being defined at different indentation levels?

```
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

    context = {'object_list' : queryset}
```

vs

```
    except EmptyPage:
        queryset = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)

        context = {'object_list' : queryset, 'class_type':CLASS_TYPE}
```

In one case you define `context` everytime, other times only when a particular branch in the exception handling is taken: is this a bug?

Comment: I am open to any kind of criticism, @downvoter please leave a comment to explain the problems of this answer.

Comment: yes, this is a bug. My intention was to use these variables in the template. thanks!

Comment: @Bruno Moving the try-catch bit into a function is ideal, as Caridorc suggested. Whenever small bugs like the above can escape scrutiny, it is time to refactor!